# Inferring Latches warning in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, latch

I have tried many ways but to no avail. It keeps having this warning: inferring latch for variable 'count_reg'.

```
    begin
process (control)
   variable count : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000"; 
    begin
        if control = "001" or control = "010" then 
            address <= count;         
            count :=  count + "0001";
        elsif control = "000" or control = "011" then
            address <= count; 
            --count :=  count; 
        else 
            count := (others => '0'); 
            address<= count;
        end if;           
end process;
```

Comment: How could it possibly work without a latch?

Comment: There is no count_reg in your code. Secondly, you are describing a counter without a clock. Counters are registered circuits which need a clock signal.

Comment: An unclocked process for a counter is a very bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should use a synchronous (clocked) process for a counter. The fact that your message references `count_reg` leads me to believe that you have not included all the relevant code.

Any asynchronous process such as the one described by your code will infer a latch for a signal that does not have an assignment in every branch of that process. In your example, the signal `count` is not assigned in the second branch (`elsif control = "000" ...`).

In some cases, there may be only one branch that assigns a value other than 'not asserted', usually `'0'`. In these cases, instead of cluttering every branch with assignments  to `'0'`, you can make this assignment right at the start of the process (before the first `if`), which will serve as a 'default', unless contradicted in one of the branches.

Your counter process should more conventionally look like this:

```
process (clk)
  variable count : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := (others => '0'); 
begin
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    if control = "001" or control = "010" then 
      address <= count;         
      count := count + "0001";
    elsif control = "000" or control = "011" then
      address <= count; 
      --count := count; 
    else 
      count := (others => '0'); 
      address <= count;
    end if;           
  end if;           
end process;
```

It is also clear that you are using the package `std_logic_arith`. This non-standard package should not be used. Instead, use `numeric_std`, and declare your `count` to have type `unsigned`.